# Chromebook 11 3810

Tags: keyboard, chromebook

I have been starting to have an issue with a couple of Dell Chromebook 11 3180. Where when you type on the keyboard random letters show on the screen.

i.e when you press N you will see NH, B and you'll see BG, @ and you'll see +@.

This has happened now on 3 different Chromebooks - and I'm stumped, as the settings are all set to UK keyboard and there isn't another language option.

I have tried to do the **Hold refresh and power button** but the machine doesn't boot at all.

If I use a USB Keyboard I can type normal.

Has anyone come across this issue before and/or know of a fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this issue, the way I sorted it out was to remove the battery for 10 seconds then putting it back.